# Package import named differently than in requirements.txt causes PyCharm warning

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, requirements.txt

This issue does not cause an actual problem when running the code, but rather is an issue of a PyCharm warning that I would like resolved so other programmers working on the project do not have to waste time investigating. The issue is that I have an import statement referencing an installed package:

```
import barcode
```

However, in my requirements.txt file the package is listed as:

```
python-barcode==0.10.0
```

This causes PyCharm to generate a warning stating that:

> Package containing module 'barcode' is not listed in project requirements less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Inspection info: This inspection warns about imported or required, but not installed packages.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way I could permanently avoid this warning for future programmers working in their own IDE, perhaps via a directive in the requirements.txt file, or something to that effect.

Answer (score 6):

To handle such cases PyCharm team has scrapped PyPI once, the result mapping is bundled with the IDE and is stored in `<PyCharm_installation_path>/helpers/tools/packages`. It was a while ago so new packages are missing. See the ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27985

Feel free to edit `helpers/tools/packages` manually and **File | Invalidate Cache & Restart** to apply changes.

---

**Update:** in PyCharm 2020.3.x the packages list is located in `plugins\python\lib\python.jar` archive. File `tools\packages` inside it.

Comment: Can you please explain more precisely where `<PyCharm_installation_path>/helpers` is located? My initial PyCharm installation was Community Edition and has had many upgrades, I can't seem to find the helpers folder.

Comment: @bad_coder Which OS do you use? You need to find where PyCharm is installed. E.g. on Windows IDE installations are stored in `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\...` by default I believe.

Comment: I'm using Win10, with current version 2020.3.2 Professional. But the folder in `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.2` does not have the `/helpes/tools/packages`...(The name of the folder is of an old version because I've been upgrading since). In `C:\Users\AppData\Local\JetBrains` there are directories named for the recent versions, but they also don't have `helpers/tools/packages`.

Comment: Ah, my bad, turns out the internal folder structure was changed. In the modern PyCharm the file is located in `plugins\python\lib\python.jar` archive (`tools\packages`). One can use e.g. WinRAR to modify the files in the archive.